# Does XSLT support lazy evaluation?

Tags: xslt-3.0

I can't see anything explicit in any of the specs.
If I ask chatgpt it invents (quite magically) a undocumented xslt command called "xsl:lazy", its a very sensible proposal, but i can find no evidence it actually exists.
When I run code in oxygen, I notice at times certain variables (I think globals) look as if they are lazy.

I hoped that 'sequences' returned from functions were lazy, but my experiments seem to indicate that they arent.

(This is using saxon PE 10.6)

Comment: It is a declarative language, it is up the implementation how exactly it implements XPath and XSLT; I know that Saxon does for instance inline variables and/or evaluate them only when/where needed. Michael Kay will certainly be able to tell you more. You can also search the documentation at https://www.saxonica.com/documentation10/index.html#!using-xsl/commandline for "lazy evaluation", https://www.saxonica.com/documentation10/index.html#!configuration/config-features with e.g. `EAGER_EVALUATION` to be enable to ease of debugging suggests "lazy evaluation" is used in most cases as the default.

Comment: the problem is that with most evaluations its largely irrelevant, but i want to “fix” over an unbounded recursion, where i need to control evaluation

Comment: If there is a concrete example where you want to improve performance or a concerned about performance then post the details. In XSLT 3 there is `xsl:iterate` for instance, to ease the task of implementing tail recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer here is maybe, but its not directly under the control of the programmer.

So for all practical purposes you need to assume no.

It IS possible to build a lazy abstraction, that will be lazy in both an eager and lazy environment though.